# React Native Image with default image if failed to load

Tags: react-native

How to display a default image for react native image component if the it failed to load the source, my API will return 404 if the requested image not found.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultSource` (ios) property of a Image. Read more at [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#defaultsource)